# prevent certain element words from being submited in a website

Tags: javascript, php, html

I would like to know how I can prevent a word from being submitted in my database

lets say I want to prevent the word 'fast car' what type of code would I use to do that. the codes that im currently using are html, javascript, php. for my website.

Comment: Show us your current code. You want to do it via server-side or client-side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use RegEx. 
On client side, refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions